# How use transmission-daemon with curlftpfs

Tags: permissions, fstab, transmission

I use an external ftp server for store data and I want to configure transmission so it can download directly into it.
But even if it has all permission (when I add the magnet, it just create the folder) after few second it gave me an error "Error: Operation not supported".

I think that is because the partition is NTFS but I'm not for sure because I can't try different file-system.

In /etc/fstab I use:

```
curlftpfs#user:pass@ip /home/media fuse rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002,user,suid,allow_other,exec,auto,utf8,_netdev  0   0
```

The user 1000 is correct and all the permission is ok.

Comment: Exactly the same problem on Mac, too.